# PyLatex and pdflatex on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pdflatex

I've been looking at generating some simple LaTeX documents in python, and I discovered PyLaTex, which seemed to be simple enough. On its PyPi package page it has an example script to run. I installed it and ran the script, but it gave the following error:

```
/bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Danyon/Documents/Uni/CSSE1001/PyLaTex/plt.py", line 60, in <module>
    doc.generate_pdf()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pylatex/document.py", line 127, in generate_pdf
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 561, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pdflatex --jobname="default_filename" "default_filename.tex"' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Clearly, I don't have pdflatex, but I can't seem to find where to get it or how to install it on Mac.
I have a Macbook Air w/ OS 10.10.3 and Python 3.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to install pdflatex, you need to install the MacTeX package. You can find this here: http://www.tug.org/mactex/

Comment: Isn't there an alternative that doesn't weigh 4Gb? Feels like a lot of stuff to download just to make simple pdfs without needing any UI.